# Blessings: how to move cursor to bottom of screen on exit?

Tags: python, python-blessings

I'm trying out some cursor-graphical output of a Python script, to give my app a nice progress bar.

I use the following to ensure my screen is blank before displaying output.

```
print term.clear
```

But when my Python script finishes, my shell prompt is output at the top of the screen, overwriting part of the progress bar.

How can I move the cursor to below my graphical output as the Python script exits? I have tried this right before exiting the script:

```
print term.move(0, term.height-1)
```

But this seems to be ignored. My shell begins output at the top of the screen.

I don't want to enter fullscreen mode, I'd like to leave the final output of the progress bar on the screen after the script finishes.

My environment is:

- OS X 10.10 Terminal in xterm-256 mode.
- Python 2.7.10
- Blessings 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the arguments to `term.move()` backwards (based on the "Moving Permanently" section [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/)).

```
move()  Parameters are y coordinate, then x coordinate.
```

Try this:

```
print term.move(term.height - 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, the docs are not clear on the arguments to the `move()` function. I tried what you suggested, but it does not change the behavior I'm seeing. The shell prompt still outputs at the top of the screen after the script exits.

Comment: I found my mistake. I executed `term.move()` where I should have executed `print term.move()`. Silly mistake!